# How do I save FileField using model's id in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created an upload function that saves an uploaded file using the pk or id.

But I get a None as a folder in the `instance.id`. I followed the instruction on the [post](http://%5Bpost%5D(https://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/25/dynamic-upload-paths-in-django/)) and I discovered that if you are using the id, you need to make sure the model instance was saved before you upload the file. Otherwise, the id hasn’t been set at that point and can’t be used.

How can get the id instead of None..?

I want to save the uploaded file to "media/id/uploaded_file

**upload_to function**

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    print('ID', instance.pk)
    return os.path.join(str(instance.id), filename)
```

**My model.py**

```
class MyVideo(models.Model):
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to guess the primary key before running object.save(), so you can't use object id while saving the object for the first time.
The primary key is chosen by the database, not django - before saving, django has no idea what the key will be.

I thought about running instance.save() in the upload_to function, but that won't work - you will be stuck in an infinite loop.

If you really need to use pk as the folder name, firstly save the object with null videofile (not in the upload_to function, but somewhere out of the model - in the view or serializer) (you might have to make this field nullable for it to be possible with `videofile= models.FileField(null=True, upload_to=upload_to))` and then, after saving, update it with the file. However it's suboptimal, you will need two database hits.

You can also use some kind of hashing function to generate your own, predictable primary key instead of using integers.

Comment: thank for response, I guess  I have to use one of the field in the model to save my filefield